# VBA creating a Userform single cell object

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've developed an application that uses excel/ VBA to interface a MySQL database in a WAMP configuration. One of the features of this application is the automatic saving of cells values, including the colors of words, font style, font size etc. The application loads up a calendar and renders the entered cell text upon workbook open.

This is achieved through breaking down the cell value into characters and storing them into a cell_value table that references other objects within my database in the following manor

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| id | employee_id | project_id |    date    |      cell_value      |     font_color     |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  1 |           1 |          1 | 2015-01-07 | the weather is crazy | 1:14:70,15:20:2000 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

this table stores the text entered by person with id=1 for project with id=1 on '2015-01-07'. The cell value is 'the weather is crazy'. the font color is listed in a comma delimited string with each element of this string delimited by a colon.

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
| starting_character_index | ending_character_index | font_color |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
|                        1 |                     14 |         70 |
|                       15 |                     20 |       2000 |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
```

I have been using the cell_selection_change event to trigger an automatic write to the database to store the contents of a global called LAST_SELECTED_CELL (as the active cell is set prior to the user making changes to it and hence does not cater for writing to the database AFTER the user makes changes to the contents of the cell).

this method works although is prone to bugs and for large amounts of cells and complex cell font/ color configurations is slow.

I was looking into using a spreadsheet embedded into a userform as potentially a better way of doing a similar process however i've found it to be quite buggy and prone to crashing. Is there a tool out there that allows you to embed a single excel 'cell' into the userform instead of an entire workbook?

If not, is there anything else that could be modified to suit my needs? Or do you have any suggestions as to how to improve my current method of storing/ rendering the data

Kind regards
Jordan

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve... What you mean by "embed a single excel 'cell' into the userform instead of an entire workbook?" I can't get it... Do you want to create a userform in which you'll be able to edit single record?

Comment: I want to embed an object that has similar functionality to an excel 'cell'. Thus affording me more control over the environment in which the users can edit a record.

Comment: Still can't get you ;( Would you like to create form like this: http://losmac.republika.pl/download/so_singlecellobject.jpg ?

Comment: I want a way of embedding a spreadsheet object into a userform (hide all the columns, rows besides col 1, row 1 i.e. a single visible cell). I have tried this method described above however the spreadsheet object once embedded into a userform causes the application to crash when doing basic manipulations to properties such as: UserForm1.Spreadsheet1.activewindow.DisplayHeadings = false
How else can I embed a spreadsheet in the userform?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no way to embed Worksheet into the userform. But...

You can imitate it via using [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278821%28v=office.15%29.aspx). It provides a way to display data as Excel Sheet displays rows and columns. It gives you a possibility to select single row or multiple rows at a time. You can make visible only one column, the rest of columns can be hidden (use ColumnWidth property).

Cheers
Maciej